# How to set width auto for elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 3 div tags.

```
<div id="thread">
          <div id="left-panel" style="width: auto;">a</div>
          <div id="content" style="width:1024px; margin: auto;">c</div>
          <div id="right-panel" style="width: auto">b</div>
</div>
```

I want `div#left-panel`, `div#right-panel` in-line with `div#content`. 
`Div#left-panel` and `div#right-panel` auto width when screen resolution change.

Please help me!

Comment: use a [grid system](http://960.gs/), so as to not re-invent the wheel :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered CSS media queries?
(Make sure to put the meta tag in the head)

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

@media(min-width: 1024px) {
    #content {}
    #left-panel {}
    #right-panel {}
}

@media(max-width: 1023px) {
    #content {}
    #left-panel {}
    #right-panel {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="thread" style="float:left;width:100%">
          <div id="left-panel" style="width:10%;float:left">a</div>
          <div id="content" style="width:70%;float:left;">c</div>
          <div id="right-panel" style="width: 20%">b</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the Current Markup plus CSS combination of yours, you cannot horizontally align your three divs.

There is one rule, which you must follow, in order to horizontally align your divs.

```
(Total(width + margin + padding) of divs to be horizontally aligned ) 
                     <= Total width of the Parent Container.
```

Now, you want to cover entire horizontal screen width (no horizontal scrollbar), then you can give percentage width to your divs and `float:left` them i.e.

```
      <div id="thread" style="width: 100%;">
           <div id="left-panel" style="width: 10%">a</div>
           <div id="content" style="width:78%;">c</div>
           <div id="right-panel" style="width: 10%">b</div>
      </div>
```

see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KRk4f/)